# How to change the text color of a nscontext menu item in cocoa mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have created a context menu and gave its connection to table, menu has items edit message and remove message, I want to change the color of "edit message" I have created an object for it, now I want to change the color of the text on the "editmessage" button.

I have tried like this.

```
NSColor *color1 = [NSColor blueColor];
NSMutableAttributedString *colorTitle1 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:[_editmessage_btn attributedTitle]];

NSRange titleRange1 = NSMakeRange(0, [colorTitle1 length]);
[colorTitle1 addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:color1 range:titleRange1];

[_editmessage_btn setAttributedTitle:colorTitle1];
```

Comment: your code has no problem. plz show other parts of it.